# Store current directory then use it later

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I want to create a batch that writes it's current location (path) in a file that is located in a different directory(C:).

I don't want it to be hard-coded so I've tried many approaches during these days but nothing worked.I thought storing the cd command in an variable might solve the problem.
Here is one of my attempts:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('cd') do set installation_path=%%i
(
    echo [General]
    echo bin: %installation_path%\bin
    echo sys: %installation_path%\sys
    echo.
    ::etc
)>"C:\file_where_I_want_to_write"
```

And instead of showing in my "file_where_I_want_to_write" my batch's directory it shows

> C:\WINDOWS\system32

Thanks for helping!

Comment: cd gives you the current directory, which is not necessarily the same as the directory containing the batch file. How do you start your batch file?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou using echo off

Comment: I mean, how do you run it? By double-clicking on the file in Explorer? By typing its name at the command prompt? If it's the latter, do you CD to its directory before you type its name?

Comment: I run it as admin due to the fact that I have to modify  C:\ drive's content.

Comment: When you run as admin, Windows puts you into the system32 directory for some weird reason. So you need to use %~dp0 as Kevin Richardson says in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, there's no need to execute anything. `%cd%` will provide you with the current directory. `%~dp0` will give you the directory containing the batch file.

```
echo %cd% > file_where_I_want_to_write
```

Updated based on comment question. If you don't want to use `%~dp0` directly, assign it to something else. Use `setlocal` and `endlocal` to confine the assignment to your batch script.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set batchdir=%~dp0
echo [General] > file_where_I_want_to_write
echo bin: %batchdir%bin >> file_where_I_want_to_write
echo sys: %batchdir%sys >> file_where_I_want_to_write
echo. >> file_where_I_want_to_write
endlocal
```

Note that `%~dp0` includes backslash.

Comment: Ok, then how should I modify my echo's content? I must store somehow the bat's directory..

Comment: Edited original. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Worked! Thanks Kevin , your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Command cd typed current path. You can use redirection > (write) or >> (append). Use:

```
cd > c:\your_path\file_where_I_want_to_write
```